# Django ModelForm fails to save "many to many" records using ModelForm and save_m2m

Tags: python, django, modelform, manytomanyfield

I am new to Django and using this project to learn it. I am able to save the Journal record but the many to many relationship does not work.

This 'create' view displays the correct form including the multi-select box with all of the cryptos listed (from Crypto model). When submitting the form the many-to-many records do not save but the Journal saves fine.

I have found a bunch of different answers to this, some are for python 2.7, but this is the simplest method based on the [Django documentation][1]. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Also, the relationship works fine in the Admin section, so I am thinking it has something to do with the Forms and/or the View & saving.*

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from crypto.models import Crypto as CryptoModel

class Journal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Journal Title', blank=False, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2000, help_text='Journal Content (HTML OK)', blank=False, null=False)
    crypto_id = models.ManyToManyField(CryptoModel, blank=True)    
    created = models.DateTimeField(help_text='Created', auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  ## String for representing the Model object, usually name field or title
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelMultipleChoiceField, widgets
from journal.models import Journal as JournalModel
from crypto.models import Crypto as CryptoModel

class JournalForm(ModelForm):
    # select multiple items box
    cryptos = ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=widgets.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 30}), queryset=CryptoModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = JournalModel
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
        ]
        labels = {
            'title': 'Journal Title',
        }
        required = [
            "title", # same as model
            "content",  # same as model
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
from journal.forms import JournalForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from journal.models import Journal as JournalModel

    def Create(request):

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = JournalForm(request.POST) # form instance
            context = {'form': form} # if errors, keep the form data on next page load

            journal = form.save(commit=False)  # False needed for many-to-many
            journal.title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            journal.content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            journal.created = timezone.now()
            journal.save()  # save the form journal data, now we have a PK
            form.save_m2m()  # save the 'form' using ManytoMany method

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/journal/')

        form = JournalForm()
        context = {'form': form}

        return render(request, 'journal/create.html', context)
```

**models.py 2**

```
from django.db import models
from crypto.models import Crypto

class Journal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Journal Title', blank=False, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=2000, help_text='Journal Content (HTML OK)', blank=False, null=False)
    crypto_id = models.ManyToManyField(Crypto, blank=True)    
    created = models.DateTimeField(help_text='Created', auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  ## String for representing the Model object, usually name field or title
```

**forms.py 2**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelMultipleChoiceField, widgets
from journal.models import Journal
from crypto.models import Crypto

class JournalForm(ModelForm):
    # select multiple items box
cryptos = ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=widgets.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 30}), queryset=Crypto.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = JournalModel
    fields = [
        "title",
        "content",
        "cryptos",
    ]
```

**views.py 2**

```
from journal.forms import JournalForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from journal.models import Journal

def Create(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JournalForm(request.POST) # form instance
        context = {'form': form} # if errors, keep the form data on next page load

        journal = form.save(commit=False)  # False needed for many-to-many
        journal.created = timezone.now()
        journal.save()  # save the form journal data, now we have a PK

        journal.crypto_id.set(form.cleaned_data.get("cryptos")) # must be after "save"
        form.save_m2m()  # save the 'form' using ManytoMany method

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/journal/')

    form = JournalForm()
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'journal/create.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this solve your problem just but this line after save your journal instance 
**journal.crypto_id.set(form.cleaned_data.get("cryptos"))**

Answer (score 0):

You've called your model and form fields different things; Django can't know they relate to the same field. The form name - `crypos` - is the correct one, you should rename your model field to that.

Also, you haven't specified the field in the `fields` list, so Django won't even try to set it on the model.

Note that in your view you don't need to set title or content, that's what `form.save` does for you already.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made the changes you suggested and posted the new code as '****.py 2'.
Unfortunately this did not change the result, the Many to Many does not save but it works fine in the Admin section. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you abdullah, adding "journal.crypto_id.set(form.cleaned_data.get("cryptos"))" to the VIEW fixed the issue.
An additional note is that this must be places after the 'journal' form is saved but before the many to many is saved.

I updated the "models.py 2", "forms.py 2" and "views.py 2" section above. This is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

you are always welcome.
yes but it after journal.save().
and set don't need to call save() from form.